# How to add image in repeatbox object

Tags: image, smartface.io

I am new in Smartface software. I want to add image in repeatbox. 
Can someone help me to add images in repeatbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop it to the repeatbox like the picture below. Remember the layout is by default "Absolute". I have set my layout to linear below.

[image]